# Is it a better or not to use Codeigniter result method when we call each model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to know the performance for code structure and Codeigniter query builder work.

I have create My_model()

```
public function select_products_from($table, $limit = 0) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    if(!empty($limit)){ $this->db->limit($limit);}
    $this->db->where(array('status' => 1));
    $this->db->order_by('viewed', 'desc');
    $dat a=  $this->db->get();
    $this->db->close();
    return $data;
}
```

In my controller

```
 private function dataProducts () {

        $this->load->model('main/products/Products_model');
        return $this->Products_model->select_products_from('products')->result();
    }


    public function sendView (){

        $this->data['products'] = $this->dataProducts();
        Render->$this->view('products',$this->data);
      }
```

Usages, I want to use multiple method

```
 return $this->Products_model->select_products_from('products')->last_row()
        ->first_row()
        ->last_row()
        ->next_row()
        ->previous_row()
        ->first_row()
            ->.....
```

Comment: Don't use Codeigniter. Laravel / Symphony are far better Frameworksl

Comment: they are good but I want to know this code will be better or not

Comment: `->result();` isn't needed on your model call.

Comment: Unless the function `newest_products_from_db('products')` is different to what you show in your example code

Comment: Now I have changed sorry for wrong,

Comment: Well in this case you do need to use `->result()` because you are returning a DB object here `$data=  $this->db->get();` `return $data`

Comment: Most people would just do `return $data->result();` from within the Model Function

Comment: Or `return $data->result_array();` if you would prefer it to return an array and not an object

Comment: I don't think so because if I return $data not result those data will collect all query method so if I want to used result_array when I call this Model which be easier

Comment: That made absolutely no sense.

Comment: you are absolutely no sense but I'm absolutely sense and easier and helfull

Comment: Im trying to help you... But you grammar and sentence structure make it hard for me to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks, Now I've update it you can test it is really easy to access another method better then to initial result() in My_Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally, I strongly prefer returning the *result* of the query to the controller, rather than the query itself. That way all your database-related stuff is nicely compartmentalized in your model, along with error handling and dealing with special cases.

For instance, if your data schema changes, currently the effect of that change will ripple through your entire program. If you return a simple array of row data, you can make sure your model still returns something the controller can use.

Note that you can return each result row as an array or an object, and you can even have the rows be instances of a class you define. In this little snippet it returns `null` when there are no results; you could return an empty array or whatever makes sense in your context:

```
$result = null;

<all the stuff to set up your query>

$query = this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $query->result();
}

return $result;
```

In you controller, you have an array of objects and you can use all php's array functions to play with it however you want. And no matter what you do to your database that part will be unaffected.

Comment: As my above function is wok and I always use it in my projects I think when Model can't query any data and $data is null value (when return null from Model) I will create an variable to from Model and check it in Controller if not empty I will call result() method